# Getting error :Cannot find method createFile($Proxy841)

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm actually working with google apps script and I was trying to use a method for uploading files, so I executed this code that I found in a web site:

```
  function doGet(e) {

 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Upload CSV to Sheet");
 var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
 var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
 form.add(formContent);  
 formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
 formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Submit'));
 app.add(form);
 return app;
 }

function doPost(e) {      // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget 
var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile; 
var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);  
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();           
//Display a confirmation message                           
var label = app.createLabel('file uploaded successfully');
app.add(label);  
 return app;  
  }
```

first I had that message error TypeError: **Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined. (line 15)** than I changed this line with this:

```
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();    
   var fileBlob = app.getElementById('thefile');// in the doPost function      

   formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setId('thefile'));</b>// I remplaced the setName with setId in the doSet function;</br>
```

And than when I executed the code again I had this error:  **Cannot find method createFile($Proxy841)**;

I really do not know what is the problem !

Can anybody please help me !
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first version is correct, are you sure you used this version to run your test ? did you use a 'dev' version or an 'exec' version ? You should not make the changes you suggested in the second part of your question, this is not how it works.

see screen capture below :

[image]

Comment: here is it is what I've done I created a new project (script as web app) I saved the project, then I run the doGet method: it works well, but again when I run the doPost method I had this message error: TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined. (line 14)!
and thank you again for your answer!

Comment: doPost can not be called alone, it is called automatically when the 'submit button' is pressed, that's how it works ;-) And indeed if you try to call doPost from the script there is not any chance that you get it to do something as 'e' is indeed not defined ! e is the 'element' returned by a doGet function. I 'd suggest you read the doc and tutorials to see how this is working (no offense :-)